# Cross Entropy Loss - Why the loss is not affected by the probability to make an error for a sample?

Tags: deep-learning

Consider a classification network of 3 classes.

I am using softmax as the last layer and cross entropy loss.

Lets consider a single sample `(x,y)` that is ran through the network, where the correct class for this example is the first class.

Lets consider two cases (two different samples for the network):

1. The softmax outputs (0.5,0.49,0.01)
2. The softmax outputs (0.5,0.25,0.25).

For both samples the loss would be `-log(0.5)`, but  my intution says that the first case should have a higher loss, because it is very close to making an error in prediction.

Am I wrong ? Why is this not a problem?

Answer (score 0):

In softmax cross entropy you only care about how likely the correct class is. You get a small loss if it is very likely or a large loss if it is unlikely. In cases like 1 the second class has a way higher gradient and is pushed down by the gradient descent to a much larger extent than class 2 in the second case.

What you are actually optimizing for in classification tasks is accuracy and in accuracy you also only care about correctly classifying all the examples and not by how much. Logits are not trustworthy anyways, as they tend to output really confident predictions of elements far from your typical set of inputs.